# When using Data augmentation is it ok to validate only with the original images?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, image-classification, image-recognition, data-augmentation

I'm working on a multi-classification deep learning algorithm and I was getting big over-fitting:
[image]

My model is supposed to classify sunglasses on 17 different brands, but I only had around 400 images from each brand so I created a folder with data augmented x3 times, generating images with these parameters:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=30,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')
```

After doing so i got these results:

[image]

I don't know if it's correct to do the validation only using the original images or if I have to use also the augmented images for the validation, also is strange for me to get higher accuracy on the validation than the training.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should validate **only** on the original images. The augmentation is there so that it can help your model generalize better, but to evaluate your model you need actual images, not transformed ones.

To do this in keras you need to define two instances of the `ImageDataGenerator`, one for training and one for validating. To train the model you need to set both generators to the `fit_generator` function.

```
train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(aug_params).flow_from_directory(train_dir)
valid_gen = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(valid_dir)

model.fit_generator(train_gen, validation_data=valid_gen)
```

It is possible to achieve a higher validation accuracy than a train accuracy if you heavily augment the training data.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, I actually was using something similar but with data augmentation in the validation, this clarify what i'm supposed to do.

Comment: Also I think you have to add this to the code to get the validation part:

`valid_gen = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(train_dir, validation_split=0.2)`

This `validation_split=0.2` if not used the model will use it `validation_split=0` as default

Comment: Yeah I meant to write a different directory containing the validation set. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 10):

Ideally, data augmentation is a step in your training pipeline, which comes **after** splitting your data into train/validation/test sets. Otherwise, you have the same data point in both training and testing, even if it a little rotated.

So your training pipeline could be something like this:

```
          +-> training set ---> data augmentation --+
          |                                         |
          |                                         +-> model training --+
          |                                         |                    |
all data -+-> validation set -----------------------+                    |
          |                                                              +-> model testing
          |                                                              |
          |                                                              |
          +-> test set --------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: thanks so much, with your permission I will use this graphic representation of my training pipeline in my presentation.

Comment: @SantiagoMarinMejia glad I could be of help. Feel free to use it ;)

Comment: I still don't track why it would make a difference whether you're applying linear transformations to the validation set. As far as I understand, and this may be wrong, the validation set does not feed directly into backprop, and backprop is the only means of biasing the resulting model. So theoretically, any image could be used as validation. Where is the failure in my logic?

Comment: @iiian what are you using your validation set for?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to validate using data augmentation. You are using data aug only for training (because you don't have enough data).
If you had much data then there was no point in data augmentation.

And you need data aug to reduce overfitting, there are other methods of reducing overfitting like dropout.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out that, though generally, we do not apply data augmentation to the validation data, there is a technique called "test time augmentation". In its simplest form, we make several predictions for each image, some of which are augmented (the same way as training) before making predictions. Then, we ensemble these predictions to make the final prediction.